# Using SFSpeechRecognizer to recognize individual Japanese characters instead of words

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Apple's `SFSpeechRecognizer` API to recognize Japanese characters (Hiragana, Katakana, Kanji). I have the recognizer set up to use the buffer from the microphone. The recognition itself is working well for words and sentences when setting it up with the "ja_JP" locale.

However, for my needs, I only need to recognize Japanese characters, not words. In my experience using the `SFSpeechRecognizer` (which isn't very long), it seems like it is geared towards recognizing words, not individual characters. For example, when I say some characters, it gives me back the right character. But for others (which I guess are closer sounding to actual words) it gives me back an actual Japanese word which may or may not have the character I want in question.

I've tried the various `SFSpeechRecognitionTaskHint` settings, but it doesn't seem to help. I've also tried to look into the `result.transcriptions` array of the `SFSpeechRecognitionTask` callback, but I don't really see alternate transcriptions with the characters I'm looking for.

Is there a particular setting that I can use to just be able to recognize letters? Or is there another setting to just recognize phonetics, irrespective of a language (i could then match the phonetic sound with the character sounds)? Am I using the wrong tool for the job?

I was hoping to use Apple's APIs, but I wonder if I need to consider another API like Google Cloud's Speech To Text API. Though this one is not free, which is a bummer. Also I'm not sure if even that one would help me with the particular problem I am having.

Thanks so much for any guidance.